# Image Warping - Bulge Effect Algorithm

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

Can any point to image warping algorithms? Specifically for bulge effect?

Comment: May you help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683954/how-can-i-do-image-warp

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See if I understood what you want. Suppose your image coordinates go from 0 to 1.

If you do:

```
r = Sqrt[(x - .5)^2 + (y - .5)^2]
a = ArcTan[x - .5, y - .5]
rn = r^2.5/.5
```

And then remap your pixels according to:

```
  x -> rn*Cos[a] + .5 
  y -> rn*Sin[a] + .5
```

You get:

[image]

You may adjust the parameters to get bigger or smaller bulges.

**Edit**

Let's see if I understood your comment about warping. The following images are generated using

```
rn = r^k {k: 1 ... 2}:
```

[image]

Comment: You don't really need to go into trigonometry. `Cos[a] = (x - .5)/r` and `Sin[a] = (y - .5)/r`

Comment: Check the algorithm in this link - http://davis.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/morph/2d.htm  Can we have an algorithm like this for bulge effect?

Comment: Thanks belisarius. I now need to implement it by adding a mesh to a Sprite in Android and applying the deformation to it. We have a library called andEngine which we can utilize. I have created another thread to proceed further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078240/image-transformation-using-sprite

Comment: @user193545 Can't help you wih that one. Good luck!

Comment: See also my followup to this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542942/looking-for-fast-image-distortion-algorithms/5555920#5555920)

Comment: Can you explain as briefly with any example

Comment: I am unable to get above effect by using your alogorithm.

Comment: @belisarius Can you help me with detecting the Objects shape witin an image ?

Comment: @Ajay May be. Post a question and ping me again :)

Comment: @belisarius I'm interested in garnering a deeper understanding of the math involved in the image warp you describe above; I've opened a thread over at math.stackexchange.com to that end: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266250/explanation-of-this-image-warping-bulge-filter-algorithm I'd really appreciate your input!  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 14):

GLSL code version:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
 vec2 cen = vec2(0.5,0.5) - gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
 vec2 mcen = - // delete minus for implosion effect
      0.07*log(length(cen))*normalize(cen);
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy+mcen);
}
```

original:

[image]

explosion:

[image]

implosion:

[image]

cheers!

Comment: how to use it in Android with bitmap?