# Image transformation using Sprite

Tags: java, android, image-manipulation, sprite

How can we use sprites to apply the image transformation in java/ android? I know we can use andEngine in android for this.

I need to apply mesh warping and produce a bulge effect using sprite.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this isn't possible with sprites, however would be interested to see if anyone else comes up with the ability to do so.