# I want to implement Image processing algorithms in iOS, can you please suggest some good guide as a starter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-processing, accelerate-framework

I found the apple documentation to be unclear. I have experience of 2 years in Image processing (Matlab and Scilab). I just need the functions for Matrix multiplication and some image conversion functions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542942/looking-for-fast-image-distortion-algorithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iOS Accelerate framework contains a fairly complete set of matrix math routines.

Using the iOS Core Graphics framework, you can create a bitmap of your desired format, and draw images into it for processing the pixel data.

You will also need to know how to map matlab data types onto Core Graphics and C language data types (memory arrays and structs, etc.)