# Processing images/video stream in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

What is good book to read on about image processing in C#, and image processing overall.

Image will be taken from a camera and will be searched for certain objects, changes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to to "basic" image manipulation functions, like color adjustments or things like that then you should probably just brush up on basic math and bit manipulation, you'd be surprised what you can accomplish with a few simple tricks (like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055625/image-warping-bulge-effect-algorithm) and this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpgraphicfilters11.aspx)).

However, if you're serious about image processing I would recommend [Algorithms for Image Processing and Computer Vision](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470643854.html), the source is in C, but that doesn't change the underlying concepts.