# Android Camera preview with funhouse mirror effect

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I created a small Android app that uses the front facing camera to shoot a selfie. But what I want to accomplish is a funhouse mirror effect.

I searched the internet trying to find a solution or a way to do this but I am guessing I am searching for the wrong terms here:

### Sample Image

[image]

Can someone push me in the right direction or how this is made? I searched for morphing, distortion etc.

**What I have right now:**
A basic camera app which is saving a taken photo using the Camera2 API in Android SDK 23

Comment: Possibly taking an image and morphing it via opengl matrix math may work and be more performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just only Camera2 API are not enough to develop an app which is like mentioned you. You should use computer vision libraries such as [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/) or [OpenGL](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).

First of all, please check [it](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/imagewarp/) out for creating theoretical background.

[Here](http://www.programering.com/a/MTO3EDNwATc.html) is an example application which is using OpenCV and it is about funny effects.

[This](https://sites.google.com/site/jaurisano/portfolio/cs-525-gpu-programming/glsl-webcam-shaders) can be another reference application which is about fun house effects and it was developed by using GLSL.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055625/image-warping-bulge-effect-algorithm) post can be helpful for you.

Moreover, you can check [it](https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv) and [it](https://github.com/tanner-rutgers/Warpy) out. And, you can use "image warping" term to search to find solutions for your problem on internet.